# ModRewrite not working properly

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am experiencing issues with `modrewrite` and `RewriteRule`. Have a look at my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# RSS Rewrites
RewriteRule abc.feed myhomepage.tld/item/category/exklusive-partner-meldungen/feed/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to rewrite the rss feeds to match the path for the old rss feeds, but when I am now opening http://myhomepage.tld/abc.feed it just shows the wordpress 404 page. I also tried some other methods like RegEx and moving lines higher to the top, but then there was something like the following url coming out:
    http://myhomepage.tld/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/item/category/exklusive-partner-meldungen/feed/

The problem is that I just want to rewrite the url and don't redirect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your rules have to go above the WordPress rules, because the last WordPress rule directs any request that isn't a physical file to WordPress for handling.

Comment: Thanks @Milo, but how to solve, that it really rewrites and not redirects?